# How do I make use of new Azure role sizes?

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

[New Azure role sizes](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/09/22/new-d-series-virtual-machine-sizes/) were announced recently and I want to test my service on `STANDARD_D1`. So I open my service definition file which starts something like this

```
<ServiceDefinition name="MyService"
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition"
   schemaVersion="2012-10.1.8">
  <WebRole name="Whatever" vmsize="Small">
```

and change `Small` to `STANDARD_D1`. The definition now fails validation - `STANDARD_D1` is not supported by the schema version I use.

It looks like perhaps my Azure SDK version is "too old" but.. Suppose I update to a later SDK version and then some new "sizes" appear - will I have to update again or is there any way to make use of new "sizes" without updating the SDK?

How do I make it work? Do I have to update to a newer SDK or is there perhaps some workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just update the SDK, I did this and worked first time after having the same issue as you.

Comment: The only supported way to update the schema is to update the SDK.  MS normally bundle changes together so they aren't in that much flux.

Comment: This is all very, very sad.

Comment: We had to upgrade. We chose 2.4 SDK and now we get this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26743648/azure-emulator-wont-accept-d-series-role This is very sad.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it (so I may be wrong) but can you try some hack? Basically the schema is validated via schema definition file stored in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\.NET SDK\[your SDK version]\schemas` folder (`ServiceDefinitionSchema.xsd`). Can you try by changing that file to include your desired VM size in there? The node you want to manipulate is `RoleSize`:

```
  <xs:simpleType name="RoleSize">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="ExtraSmall" />
      <xs:enumeration value="Small" />
      <xs:enumeration value="Medium" />
      <xs:enumeration value="Large" />
      <xs:enumeration value="ExtraLarge" />
      <xs:enumeration value="A5" />
      <xs:enumeration value="A6" />
      <xs:enumeration value="A7" />
      <xs:enumeration value="A8" />
      <xs:enumeration value="A9" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

Please give it a try and let me know if that works. If not, then I will delete my answer.

Comment: I tried this - I edited the .xsd and the .csdef is now displayed okay but when I try to create a service package I get a schema validation error message. No idea where it comes from though.

Comment: Aah ... the hack didn't work. Let me also try in a little while and see if I can make it work.