# Azure Emulator Won't Accept D-Series Role

Tags: azure, azure-role-environment

If I try to debug an Azure project using the new D-Series sizes, I get an error saying that the Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.  I'm using the latest 2.4 tools.  Is there a way around this or do I have to wait for 2.5?

Another weird issue is that I have to manually edit the csdef and re-open the role properties to even get the choices for the new sizes.  I verified that my projects have been upgraded to 2.4 as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was resolved with SDK v2.5